# want to fetch image from web to backend flask but its showing badrequest key error

Tags: python, forms, flask, file-upload

I am trying to fetch a single Image from user but has been constantly facing following error
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'file'

following code is written on main.html file

```
<form action="/predict" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" ,name = "file", >
        <button type = 'submit'>Submit </button>
    </form>
```

and below here is how I am trying to retrieve the image data

```
@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
       if  request.method== 'POST':
              # image_data = request.form['file1']
              image_data = request.form["file"]
              print(image_data)
              return 'ok'
```

Comment: `type="file"` is avaliable as `request.file`

Comment: you can use `.get("file")` instead of `["file"]` and you will get `None` instead of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access files sent via http request, you must use the `files` property of the `request` object:

change

```
image_data = request.form["file"]
```

to:

```
image_data = request.files["file"]
```